# Git Discard all changes locally and remote after a certain commit

Tags: git, github

I'm having a bit of trouble reverting back to a certain git commit. I'm using Github and Sourcetree. How can I discard all changes after the commit "Typo" and revert to that state and work from there?

I've tried reset, but that doesn't seem to do the trick. If there is a terminal commando for git for this that is okay too.

[image: My mess :-(]

Answer (score 2):

You can revert all your files under your working directory and index by typing following this command.

```
git reset --hard <SHAsum of your commit>
```

For example if i have a commit that is called commit 4a155e5b3b4548f5f8139b5210b9bb477fa549de
Then i would write:

```
git reset --hard 4a155e5
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple `git checkout -b newBranch <SHA of Typo commit>` should do the trick. It would create a new branch pointing to your desired commit and checkout the content locally. 
This way you will not lose the commits after the `Typo`. If you need to remove them you will be able to remove the branch containing them, using: `git branch -D <name of the branch>`
You can establish the `SHAsum` using `git log`.